# How do I hide or collapse by default generated files on a phabricator diff?

Tags: phabricator

I've been using phabricator for some time now and I always find it hard to review code where there are many generated files as snapshots and files ending on 'test.jsx.snap' for example.

I was looking for an option on .arcconfig to collapse files that match certain paths by default

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this script](https://github.com/CarlaTeo/Collapse-Phabricator-Snapshots) to be run using Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey that collapses all the snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

There's a server-side configuration for Differential, `differential.generated-files` that allows files (actually, regular expressions matching file paths) to be treated as generated, and they'll show up in the reviews collapsed by default.

Assuming you can insert arbitrary text into those files, you can also add the token `@generated` into the files themselves, and Differential will do the same thing.

There's [an open task](https://secure.phabricator.com/T784) with some discussion on the specific form you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure `arc` to mark certain paths as generated at diff creation time:

```
      'generated-paths' => array(
        'type' => 'list<regex>',
        'help' => pht(
          'Paths that are generated. These paths are not normally useful for '.
          'code review and will be shown as collapsed in the Differential UI.'),
        'default' => array(),
        'example' => '["(^src/__phutil_library_map__\\.php$)"]',
      ),
```